# Karatsuba multiplier

Tags: algorithm, recursion, multiplication

I am multiplying two n-digit positive integers with an n-digit Karatsuba multiplier. But most of the times, the sub-problems still have to deal with two n-digit numbers. So should I use the n-digit Karatsuba algorithm again recursively to the sub-problems? Is there any redundancy in this approach? Will it compromise the computation time (O(n^1.5)) in any way?

Comment: Something doesn't sound right here; you shouldn't be getting back n-digit numbers during Karatsuba multiplication.  Can you post your code or pseudo code so we can look over it?

Comment: A Karasuba reduction reduces an N x N product into three N/2 x N/2 products. That's where the `O(N^1.585)` comes from. There's a threshold where you should switch back to `O(N^2)` multiply.

Comment: Please post the cod and show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to use the same approach. Still for small enough numbers use some other approach as the overhead of adding digits may be too big.

But it is not true you need again to multiply n-digit numbers, you will need to multiply `n/2` digit numbers. That is the whole point of the method.

Comment: Let's multiply 49 x 56 (two 2-digit numbers)

a = 4 x 5
d = 9 x 6

e = (4 + 9) x (5 + 6) - a - d
=>e = 13 x 11 - a - d


We can see that we need to again multiply 13 and 11 which are again two 2-digit numbers. So should I again apply the 2-digit Karatsuba multiplier on them?

Comment: I don't think small digit numbers are good example. The number of digits on each iteration is in the order of n/2, but it may have a constant added(1 in this case). That is why I said for small numbers a different approach works better. As adding two n/2 numbers may result in a carryover, the number of digits may increase with 1 and this is what happens in this case.